# How to create statement if contains "!"

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var input = message.content.toUpperCase();
if(input.indexOf("!")
{
bot.sendMessage(message, "!!!");
}
```

Help would be great, also earlier input was defined earlier

Comment: `if(input.indexOf("!") > -1)`

Comment: Your parentheses on line 2 are not balanced. For more information on `indexOf`, please read the documentation; [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is a good source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** method returns the index if found else returns `-1`. In your case `.indexOf("!")` return `0` and it's a `false` value and if statement never gets executed,so update your condition based on that.

```
if(input.indexOf("!") > -1)
```

or

```
if(input.indexOf("!") != -1)
```

Comment: Thank you that was all it needed

Comment: @JoshP : glad to help you :)

Comment: @Josh, accept Pranav's answer (it's a small green tick at the left), it gives you internet beans!